# ANTLR3 NoViableAltException

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

This is the part of my grammar that make error:

```
expr : func_name '(' constant (',' constant)* ')' ;

constant
    :    '"' (~'"')* '"';

WS      :      (' '|'\t')+ {skip();} ;
```

And the error is about this part of text:

```
"w9ygS99Qp_", "vuPfq6YcbX"
```

The interpreter of ANTLRWorks give me the next leaves, which have a node constant as parent:

```
"
w9ygS99Qp_",
"
```

Then it is an NoViableAltException error.

Normally, it should have this leaves:

```
"
w9ygS99Qp_
"
```

Apparently, the problem is the _ before the ", because I tried to suppress the _, but the same error appears when te parser meet the next _"

Comment: The ANTLRWorks 1.x interpreter is unreliable. It doesn't produce the same results as ANTLR 3 does for the same grammar, so you shouldn't consider its output usable for either success or error cases.

Comment: OK, thus I have to compile the grammar in Java, and then test it in Java, if I understood well?

Comment: Maybe should I use ANTLR4, to be able to use ANTLRWorks correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `constant` should be a lexer rule, not a parser rule. Inside a parser rule, `~'"'` matches **any token** other than a double quote-token. It does *not* match **any charatcer** except the double quote-char.

Do it like this instead:

```
expr : func_name '(' Constant (',' Constant)* ')' ;

Constant
    :    '"' (~'"')* '"';
```

> OK, thus I have to compile the grammar in Java, and then test it in Java, if I understood well?

Yes, or use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead. The debugger works like a charm.

To test in plain Java, do something like this:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("name(\"w9ygS99Qp_\", \"vuPfq6YcbX\")"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.expr();
  }
}
```

> Maybe should I use ANTLR4, to be able to use ANTLRWorks correctly?

If you have a choice to use either ANTLR3 or ANTLR4, then go for ANTLR4. Note that there's a new (rewritten) version of ANTLRWorks for ANTLR4 grammars: http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks

Comment: What you propose work very well, but the problem is that I want to have three leaves, two containing the ", and one with the comment itself, and a single lexer rule doesn't allow to obtain this result.

Comment: You can't reasonably do that without going to an awful lot of messy hoops inside your lexer. The best approach is to do as I suggested, and strip the quotes from the token by doing `'"' (~'"')* '"' setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length() - 1));`, or doing so at a later time (while walking the AST).

Comment: The following:

`CONSTANT : '"' (~'"')* '"' {setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length() - 1))};`

seems to generate the same thing as previously, the " are still in the leave.

Comment: @Pico, you're probably still using the interpreter: **don't**.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry. With the debugger, it works. Thank you very much for your help.